# OpenGL, a very basic shader not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I am learning OpenGL through [TheCherno Project](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheChernoProject).
The code below is from there and I faithfully reproduce it for my learning purpose. I have also added both vertex and fragment shaders as well.

My issue here is in my square output I don't see the color at all and I am guessing it is using the default shader.

```
 int main(void)
 {
 GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    std::cout << "ERROR GLEW" << std::endl;

std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

float positions[] = {
        -0.5f,-0.5f,    //0
         0.5f, -0.5f,   //1
         0.5f, 0.5f,    //2
        -0.5f, 0.5f     //3
};

unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
};

unsigned int buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * 2 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


unsigned int ibo;
glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

ShaderSourceProgram shader = ParseShader("res/shaders/Basic.shader");
//std::cout << "VERTEX" << std::endl;
//std::cout << shader.VertexShader << std::endl;
unsigned int shaderProgram = CreateShader(shader.VertexShader, shader.FragmentShader);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

The shaders:

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0)in vec4 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
};

#shader fragment
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
};
```

**EDIT:** [Please click here for the entire project (github)](https://github.com/jxgeoffrey/OpenGL/blob/master/OpenGL/src/Source.cpp)

Comment: Please add your shader loading code. And please also query the result of `glGetError()` to see if there are any errors in your program. I'm quite sure there are some of them because in 3.3 Core Profile you are required to use VAOs.

Comment: There are several fails. `glBufferData` needs the number of bytes, that '6' is wrong. You need a VAO. `glVertexAttribPointer` is also wrong used. Better look for another tutorial ;)

Comment: And if you have to link to a video (which is inherently bad because we have to watch the whole video to find the relevant parts), then at least link to the correct one. What you linked to is a C++ Hello World program.

Comment: @Ripi2 Yeah the buffer size is wrong. In the next tutorial he pointed it out and changed it. The code I shared was from before that :)

Comment: @BDL added my github link for the source

Comment: This shows why you need to start thinking on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ripi2 pointed out your `glBufferData()` calls, while not exactly wrong (they *over*request buffer space), aren't exactly correct either.  Since you're using raw arrays you can use a straight `sizeof(<arrayname>)` for the `size` parameter:

```
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( positions ), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
...
glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( indices ), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
```

I suspect your (unknown) shader loader might be wonky since my personal one worked fine.

All together:

[image: screenshot of green square]

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* shader, ... )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, shader );
        while( shader )
        {
            const GLenum type = va_arg( args, GLenum );
            AttachShader( prog, type, shader );
            shader = va_arg( args, const char* );
        }
        va_end( args );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

int main( void )
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if( !glfwInit() )
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL );
    if( !window )
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    if( glewInit() != GLEW_OK )
        std::cout << "ERROR GLEW" << std::endl;

    std::cout << glGetString( GL_VERSION ) << std::endl;

    float positions[] = {
        -0.5f,-0.5f,    //0
        0.5f, -0.5f,   //1
        0.5f, 0.5f,    //2
        -0.5f, 0.5f     //3
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * 2 * sizeof( float ), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( float ) * 2, 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

    unsigned int ibo;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &ibo );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo );
    glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof( unsigned int ), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    const char* vert = GLSL
    (
        330 core,
        layout(location = 0)in vec4 position;

        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = position;
        };
    );

    const char* frag = GLSL
    (
        330 core,
        out vec4 color;

        void main()
        {
            color = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
        };
    );

    unsigned int shaderProgram = Program::Load
        (
        vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
        frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
        NULL
        );
    glUseProgram( shaderProgram );

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr );

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers( window );

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram( shaderProgram );

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah the buffer size is wrong. In the tutorial he pointed it out and changed it. The code I shared was before that :) So, the code I shared worked without any change? I have to check then properly and will get back.

Answer (score 0):

`glUseProgram()` needs to be called after shaders are compiled and linked. Here's a piece of a sample code:

```
int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLAD
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    float TriangleVertices[] = {
        -0.3f, -0.3f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.3f, 0.0f,
         0.3f,  -0.3f, 0.0f
    };
    
    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    //BindVertexArray for modifying it
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TriangleVertices), TriangleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    const char* vertexShaderSource = "\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
            "void main()\n"
            "{\n"
            "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"
            "}\0";


    unsigned int vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);


    const char* fragmentShaderSource = "\n"
        "out vec4 FragColor; \n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.7f, 0.5f, 1.0f); \n"
        "} \n";

    unsigned int fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    unsigned int shaderProgram;
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();


    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        
        //// draw triangle using the data from the VAO
        
        //glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;

}
```